# How to use connector common property i.e., service-overrides of Mule 3 in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4

We want to process all messages from JMS MQ(inbound) as a group at once in Mule 4.
To achieve this functionality in Mule 3, we are using custom java classes and service-overrides in the JMS connector. How to achieve the same functionality in Mule 4.

```
Mule 3 : Code snippet.
<jms:connector name="jmsGroupsConnector" specification="1.1" 
        validateConnections="true" connectionFactory-ref="MQFactoryGroup" 
        doc:name="JMS" createMultipleTransactedReceivers="false" 
        numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="1"> 
        <service-overrides 
            transactedMessageReceiver="com.XXX" 
            messageFactory="com.XXX"
            messageReceiver="com.XXX" /> 
</jms:connector>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no service overrides in Mule 4. You would need to share exactly what your custom code does to see if it is there is an equivalent feature in Mule 4. If it is just to aggregate messages you may find the [aggregators module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/aggregators-module/1.0/) useful to implement this without the need for custom code.

Comment: We are getting a single message(string) at a time from IBM MQ(inbound) in mule 4. But we need all the messages in the queue at once as an arraylist. Using aggregators module, we may not got a collection of string at once from queue.

Comment: @Uday This kind of requirement could have been easier if it is  cleared  from source system before passing in to the queue.  If that is immutable 1. Inside your api , you can have Http/https (basically rest service)-> aggregator (to collection all your string message based on condition) -> original Queue  2. Create new Queue -> aggregate message based on condition -> push message to your original queue